# Codesignal : "Rectangle rotation" And can you explain why mine is wrong?

Tags: java, count, rotation

Question :

A rectangle with sides equal to even integers a and b is drawn on the Cartesian plane. Its center (the intersection point of its diagonals) coincides with the point (0, 0), but the sides of the rectangle are not parallel to the axes; instead, they are forming 45 degree angles with the axes.

How many points with integer coordinates are located inside the given rectangle (including on its sides)?

answer :

```
int solution(int a, int b)
{
    a/=Math.sqrt(2);
    b/=Math.sqrt(2);

    return (2*a*b+a+b)|1;
}
```

It bothers me too much... Plz help me

My code :

```
int solution(int a, int b) {
    double k1 = b/Math.sqrt(2);
    double k2 = a/Math.sqrt(2);
    
    int ini = ((int)(Math.floor(min(k1, k2))))*2+1;
    int temp=ini;
    int num=0;
    
    while(temp>0){
        num += temp*2;
        temp-=2;
    }
    
    return num+ini*((int)(Math.floor(Math.abs(k2-k1)/2))*2+1);
}
double min(double a, double b){
    return a>b ? b:a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make our lives easier, we first rotate the entire cartesian plane.
Thus, the SW-NE diagonal becomes the X-axis and the SE-NW diagonal becomes the Y-axis.

We then "zoom out" a bit, in order to have diagonal lengths = 1, effectively reducing them by a sqrt(2) factor.

Because we zoom out the entire plane, the size of the rectangle must be corrected with the same factor.
That is what these two lines do:

```
a/=Math.sqrt(2);
b/=Math.sqrt(2);
```

Now we just need to count the points according to the corrected rectangle length.

If you do some simulations, you will identify two cases:

- Case 1: a+b is even
  -- number of points: (a+1)*(b+1) + a*b = 2*a*b + a + b + 1 (odd result)
- Case 2: a+b is odd -- number of points: (a+1)*b + a*(b+1) = 2*a*b + a + b (odd result)

The only difference is the "+1" in Case 1.
Thus, we can always compute (2*a*b + a + b), and add 1 only if it is even.
That is exactly what  the line below does:

```
return (2*a*b+a+b)|1;
```